# How to extend "Recall Transaction" screen in AX 2012 POS

Tags: c#, dynamic-programming, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012-r3, dynamics-ax-xpo

I want to extend/customize the "Recall transaction" form. I didn't find "Recall transaction" form in SDK. Any clue/hint?

Answer (score 0):

I also could not find any reference of "Recall Transaction form" in Retail SDK.

For this reason, I have decompiled the .dll POSProcess and found the classes, **frmSuspendedTrans** and **frmSuspendedTransSearch**, where I found the references to Recall Transaction form.

I think that this particular form is not available for editing (although I'm not 100% sure because I did not have time to search more).

Perhaps, you can create a new form and inherit some features of
  LSRetailPosis.POSProcesses.frmSuspendedTransSearch.

If possible, open a incident at Microsoft. Any news, please, share with us.